# Creating a mask on a UICollectionViewCell to show white text.

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, cagradientlayer

I currently have a UICollectionViewCell that can have any image as it's background. The problem with this is that I am using white text over the cell as shown [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDOLf.jpg)

I would like to be able to have a similar effect to [this.](https://i1.creativecow.net/u/253346/whiteletteringwhitebackground.jpg)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You can add a shadow on the label (if there is a label) with `NSAttributedString` and the `NSShadowAttributeName` attribute.

Comment: I think below code help for you UIColor *color = label.textColor;
    Label.layer.shadowColor = [color CGColor];
    nameLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
    nameLabel.layer.shadowOpacity = .9;
    nameLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
    nameLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;

Comment: Okay I think I have managed to get it working. http://imgur.com/Gxx2AFX

Comment: Is there any way of using a gradient to do this?